# How to use quicksearch jquery plugin for a particular column?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, quick-search

I have a gridview on which i want to apply quick-search plugin of jquery.I have implemented it successfully. But i want the search should be only according to a particular column, like:- I have three columns in a row. firstname, lastname, address. Now i want to search for firstname only.But normally quciksearch plugin is searching from whole gridview. I have done it from link :-**http://www.misfitgeek.com/2011/06/filtering-an-asp-net-gridview-control-with-jquery/**

Please help me as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know my code is not good technically its just completed my task. i am writing the code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ctl00_InnerBody_txtfirstnamesearch").quicksearch("table tbody tr", {
            selector: 'span',
            delay: 100,
            loaderText: 'Loading...'

        });
    });
</script>
```

and in gridview :-

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' ID="lbl" runat="server">
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: The above code helped me to resolve the issue.Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You may define custom testQuery finction and filter by cell index in row:

```
$("#<%= SearchTextBox.ClientID %>")
.quicksearch("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tbody tr",
     {
          'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
               return $(row).index() == 0 || // show header
               $(row).children(":nth-child(3):contains('" + query[0] + "')").length > 0;
          }
     }
);
```